# Downloading through IE in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to know a way in which I can monitor the download of an application in IE through Perl. I am doing automation, and as soon as the download completes, I need to start a Perl script for processing the downloaded application. The download has to be done through IE. I found out `IE::Mechanize` and `LWP::Simple` in Perl but I want something which is a combination of both. I also looked at `URLDownloadToFile` but couldn't understand how to implement it in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Perl through a browser (IE), use Selenium RC.

Other than that, for web automation I usually use WWW::Mechanize.

Comment: can u give me a little more help with selenium RC. Method which tells u abt the download progress or similar..